# Find paragraphs in text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement an 'edit' button on a django website using javascript. I'm very new to javascript though.

In django it's pretty easy to split the text into paragraphs, you just code it like this {{ text|linebreaks }} and django adds `<p>` tags dynamically. To make the transition smooth (after sending fetch request and receiving response) with javascript I need to create a function that loops through the edited text and generates `<p>` tags as well.

However I dont' even know where to start. How exactly do you find where each paragraph ends using javascript?

Comment: Do you have a sample input and output?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+create+p+tags+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

you can split the text into paragraphs based on line breaks by using `<br>`. Let's assume that after fetching the edited text from Django, you have it stored in a variable called `editedText`. To generate `<br>` tags for each paragraph, you can follow these steps:

Split the text into an array of paragraphs using the `split()` function.
Loop through the array of paragraphs and join them using `<br>` tags to generate the new formatted text.

```
<div id="edited-text">{{ edited_text }}</div>
<button onclick="formatEditedText()">Edit</button>

<script>
function formatEditedText() {
  const editedTextDiv = document.getElementById('edited-text');
  const editedText = editedTextDiv.innerHTML;

  const paragraphs = editedText.split('<br>');

  let formattedText = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    formattedText += `<p>${paragraphs[i]}</p>`;
  }

  editedTextDiv.innerHTML = formattedText;
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly this, but I managed to solve the problem thanks to your answer,